# Accessing Visual SVN from ASP.Net using sharpsvn API

Tags: asp.net, svn, visualsvn-server, sharpsvn

has any one tried to access [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) repositories through ASP.Net using SharpSVN API ? if yes, what were the challenges ?

Answer (score 3):

There is one thing you should take a look at when using [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.net/) in ASP.NET, see [this forum post](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=728&dsMessageId=107725)